# Ignoring the property from a CSS class

Tags: css

Hi I am trying to implement RTL in my website. I have a check box like this in CSS

```
.labeled-checkbox .checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

In case of RTL language a class will be added dynamically to the html file and a new style will be added to CSS as below.

```
.locale-right-to-left .labeled-checkbox .checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Now in this case check box should be moved to the left most direction . But its not happening as both the left and right property are added to the  check box. Is there any way we can ignore the right:0px and only left:0px can be used in case of RTL languages?

Comment: Please provide a Fiddle.

Comment: have you tried adding `right: auto;`?

Answer (score 4):

Add `right: auto;` to your RTL class

```
   .locale-right-to-left .labeled-checkbox .checkbox {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: auto; 
      margin-top: -1px;
    }
```

Comment: Check updated answer for a working example. I've made some assumptions about your markup because you haven't provided any.

Comment: Thanks @3rror404  . itworks .I am new to CSS and html. can you explain how it works in the 2nd case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `right: auto` in your `.locale-right-to-left .labeled-checkbox .checkbox` styles to override the `right` rule

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right

Answer (score 0):

If you add a css class dynamically, you can also remove one. So add a class `locale-left-to-right` as default so then you can write the following:

```
.locale-left-to-right .labeled-checkbox .checkbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```